# cyrillic shows in db fine, appears as ??? on website

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I tried to switch all my content in the database to UTF8 because some characters weren't showing up. I switched everything in the database, all column collations, tables, etc to
utf8_general_ci. I made sure my header.php specifies the charset as UTF8:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I added

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

to .htaccess. I made a php.ini file and put

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
mbstring.internal_encoding=utf-8
mbstring.http_output=UTF-8
mbstring.encoding_translation=On
mbstring.func_overload=6
```

in it. I also exported everything in the database as utf8, dropped everything and imported. In the database itself, the characters show up correctly. Everything looks great. But on the website, in both local and live environments and on FF, Chrome, and IE, there are only ?????. The last thing I did was go into my config.php and edit the db stuff directly.

```
<?php
ob_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    } 

//set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');

//database credentials
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('DBPASS','');
define('DBNAME','dbname');
define('CHARSET', 'utf8');

//application address
define('DIR','http://websiteurlcom');
define('SITEEMAIL','email@whatever.com');

try {

    //create PDO connection 
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS.";charset=".CHARSET);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //show error
    echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    exit;
}

//include the user class, pass in the database connection
include('classes/user.php');
$user = new User($db); 
?>
```

I also ran the query:

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

directly in the database. I checked the encoding of both Notepad++ (utf8 without BOM) and Brackets. None of that has worked. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Did you restart all services after making changes to system files? Plus, what's your PHP version?

Comment: Another thing you can try is `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'` in the constructor.

Comment: I'm using  a subdomain for one of my godaddy sites, I'm not sure what you mean by resetting the systems. I suppose I could try resetting XAMPP and see what happens. I'm using PHP 5.4 with GD.

Comment: Temporary workaround I've found while waiting to fix the issue, I converted the cyrillic into straight HTML and just put that into the db. Here's the thing I used to save from having to look up each character. http://web.forret.com/tools/html.asp

Comment: Have you tried adding `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");` and encode the Collation column in your table to `utf8_bin` see if that helps.

Comment: Indeed, I did. My o.p. shows all the things I've done so far.